# Very very weird problem with UIImageView property - I can access it then I can't, and it's not nil

Tags: iphone, ipad

Very very weird problem with UIImageView property on iPad application

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UIImageView* coverImage;
}
@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView* coverImage;
```

… more code

```
@implementation MyViewController

@synthesize coverImage;
```

… more code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString* imageName = @"my_image.png";
    UIImage* tempImage = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
    [self.coverImage setImage:tempImage];
}
```

The above code WILL display the image.

In another part of code:

```
-(IBAction) stopButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    [self.coverImage setHidden:YES];
    NSLog(@"coverImage desc: %@", [coverImage description]);
}
```

The image will NOT disappear.  I know the reference to the image isn't nil, because it gives me this output:

2010-05-29 17:37:40.706 MyApp[95360:207] coverImage desc: UIImageView: 0x5128420; frame = (0 0; 1024 768); autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = CALayer: 0x512bed0

In addition, if I move the code in viewDidLoad to another part of the class, and try to execute it from there, it fails to show the image at all.

Comment: Probably a dumb suggestion, but whenever something doesn't seem to be happening in a view the first thing I always try is calling [view setNeedsDisplay:YES]...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that still didn't work.  What's odd is when I try to set the image to a new image or set it's hidden property anywhere in the class, it fails.  It only works in viewdidLoad.

Comment: Can you get the containing view to redraw? If you change its colour (or some such change appropriate to whatever kind of view it is), how does that affect the image view?

Comment: Well, now it works.  To make matters worse, I don't know why.  I tried setNeedsDisplay again and then everything started to work right.  Even after I commented out setNeedDisplay, it still worked.  Go figure.

Comment: Heh. I can see how that would be a bit vexing, but as long as it stays working it'd be churlish to complain!

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing `self.coverImage` with just `coverImage`:
`self.coverImage` will invoke a different setter to just `coverImage`.

Hope this helps and the problem is resolved,
jrtc27

Comment: The self.coverImage basically means getCoverImage, and makes no difference.  I just put it in my code for clarity.  But just to make sure I wasn't missing something, I tried it anyway and it still didn't work. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is there a chance that your ViewController is being released?

Comment: No the VC continues to run fine in the app.  There are other things happening, but not in relation to the image. I did the NSLog as shown above and it's not nil, so I'm fairly certain the image and VC aren't released.

Comment: Remember that just because they are not nil does not necessarily mean they have not been released.  I am trying to recreate your problem right now.  Will get back if I have any luck.

Comment: See my comment above.  Thank for your help.